# How to specify delta in a non-symmetric way (in an epsilon-delta proof)? Or what is the strategy that proves $\sqrt{x} \to \sqrt{a}$ when $x \to a$?

Tags: notation, epsilon-delta

**The problem**.  Prove $\lim \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}$ as $x \to a$ given $a > 0$. The problem suggests using the identity $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| = |x - a|/(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a})$.

This problem is tricky for me because I must be careful with numbers $a$ that are close to zero, after all I cannot take the square root of a negative number.  So I tried: given $a > 0$, let's restrict $a/2 < |x - a| < (a + 1)/2$.  This restriction works, but this is the first time that I find myself in need of a non-symmetric restriction.  I suppose there must be a way to specify a non-symmetric delta.  How is that usually written?  I suppose I can describe it in words.  Let $d > 0$ be such that $a/2 < |x - a| < (a + 1)/2$ or let $d$ be $e(\sqrt{4a/3} - \sqrt{a})$, whichever $d$elta is smaller.

And then I can finish the proof saying that the restriction implies $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a/3} - \sqrt{a}}$$

and then using the problem's suggested identity we end up with $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < e$.

**Reference**.  This is problem 37 in section 2.4 of James Stewart's Calculus, 6th edition.  The book suggests (with a red icon on the number of the problem) that there's a visual help for the problem, but this help would be in some website --- I guess --- and I could not find any help in [Stewart's website](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/).  I suppose this edition is too old and there's no online help anymore?

Comment: You seem to have the right idea about dealing with an asymmetric function. Yes, you can use the smaller $\delta.$ You can go even smaller if you find it convenient to do so.

Comment: I think you're saying that my attempt is successful?  (Sorry. I'm slow!)  I wonder you would have written it.

Comment: To be honest, I could not quite see what you were thinking in the part that came after choosing the smaller $\delta.$ Usually you'd want to fill in the steps a little more explicitly for a proof like this. But the insight about the smaller $\delta$ is huge, lots of people have trouble with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the expression of the proposed suggestion.

Indeed, if let $|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$, it yields that:
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| & = \left|\frac{x - a}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}\right| = \frac{|x - a|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}} \leq \frac{|x - a|}{\sqrt{a}} < \frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\sqrt{a}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo. (Corrected.)  You seem to have a very elegant proof.  I wonder how did you figure it out.  Why is it that $\delta_\epsilon / \sqrt{a} < \epsilon$?  (What is your delta exactly?)

Comment: We want to prove that the next claim is true, where $f:(0,+\infty)\to(0,+\infty)$ is given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$:

$$(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in(0,+\infty))(|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \varepsilon)$$

This amounts to find a $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ so that the proposition above holds. As it has been shown, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, it suffices to consider $0 < \delta_{\varepsilon} < \varepsilon\sqrt{a}$ in order to make things work.

Comment: The equation in the book is equivalent to yours. Since $\sqrt x + \sqrt a$ is positive, it is its own absolute value.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia, I get your answer now.  You have a very elegant proof of this one.  That's wild.  I'm impressed.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1145880 you are welcome! I am glad I could help.